# how can I prevent Ubuntu from sleeping when plugged in?

Tags: suspend, 20.04

Under "power management" I have

- Put computer when inactive for: Never
- When laptop lid is closed: Suspend
- Put display to sleep when inactive for: 30 minutes

this used to work under 19.10.  I've upgraded to 20.04 (Focal Fossa) and now if I leave the laptop plugged in and walk the dog, the laptop is asleep when I return.  If I push the power button it resumes, but I don't want it to sleep when plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

This should be controllable in the power section of settings. Suspend & Power Button > Automatic Suspend, as seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLseP.png