# How to stop Ubuntu from suspending due to inactivity?

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management

When I leave my laptop unattended overnight, in the morning, it's always suspended, even though it's plugged in, which interferes with running processes.

How do I disable this?

Under Settings/Power, "Automatic Suspend" is set to "When on battery power" so I don't know what's causing it to suspend.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Cinnamon so the Power management page looks different but there are two profiles, one for AC power and one for battery. Take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241124/how-can-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-sleeping-when-plugged-in?rq=1) perhaps the suggested answer can help. Refer to the link which displays an image.

Comment: Just before you "leave my laptop unattended", do (on a command line) `date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp`. In the morning, `sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"` will show system log messages that will include information about your problem. Read `man journalctl less`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.